# Inherited Resources Rails 4 Update Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inherited-resources

My application is using Rails 4 with `inherited_resources`.  Very oddly, the `update` action does not appear to work.  When try to submit the form on the `edit` page, I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in Admin::FaqsController#update
wrong number of arguments (6 for 1)
```

There are 6 fields in the form.  My controller is like this:

```
class Admin::FaqsController < Admin::AdminController
  inherit_resources
  respond_to :html
  actions :index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy

  private

  def resource_params
    params.require(:faq).permit(:title, :slug, :body, :publish_immediately, :published_at, :status)
  end
end
```

Why is this happening?  Is it an incompatiblity with Rails 4, and I just need to do the `update` action myself?

Comment: Are you sure your Faq form is well formatted? What happens if you replace `params.require(:faq).permit(:title, :slug, :body, :publish_immediately, :published_at, :status)` with `params.require(:faq).permit!`?

Comment: Same thing.  I double-checked the request data too, and the correct fields are present.  That error is clearly coming from somewhere in the gem, unfortunately it doesn't give me a full stack trace.  If it did, I might be able to figure out what the problem is.  Is there a way to make it show the full stack track?

Answer (score 2):

Seems I figured it out.  I went back through the documentation and saw that I was using the params permit incorrectly.  I thought it was called `resource_params` with a `require` call, but it is as follows:

```
class Admin::FaqsController < Admin::AdminController
  inherit_resources
  respond_to :html
  actions :index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy

  private

  def permitted_params
    params.permit(faq: [:title, :slug, :body, :publish_immediately, :published_at, :status])
  end
end
```

The difference is in calling the method `permitted_params`, and returning the entire params array with specific fields within it permitted, instead if only the resource's fields.